# Adding all products in cart on clicking single product

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am using Meteor with React to create an E-commerce app but getting a few problems while adding a product in a cart.

1.On adding a single product to cart, all products get added to the cart.

2.After adding products, products cannot be added again, Meteor showing error:409 of same id.

Here is the code:

This is the function which adds product in the cart collection.

```js
addToCart() {
    if(Meteor.userId()) {
        return this.state.productsList.map((product) => {
            Carts.insert({
                _id:product._id,
                itemName: product.itemName,
                itemDesc:product.itemDesc,
                uploadedAt:new Date().getTime(),
                price:product.price,
                addedBy:Meteor.userId()
            });
        });
    }else{
        console.log('Please login to add this product');
    }
}
```

I am using this function call while rendering the products on the page on a click event of a button:

```js
renderProductsList(){
    return this.state.productsList.map((product)=>{
        return (
            <div key={product._id}>
                <h4>{product.itemName}</h4>
                <p>{product.itemDesc}</p>
                <img src={product.itemImgUrl}/>
                <p>${product.price}</p>
                <button onClick={this.addToCart.bind(this)}>Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
        );
    });
}
```

Please tell me how to fix these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `map` and adding all the product items instead of the clicked one.

To solve the issue:

**1.** First pass a unique value of each product in onClick method:

```
<button onClick={this.addToCart.bind(this, product._id)}>Add to Cart</button>
```

**2.** Then use `forEach` to iterate all the product items and check if the id matches then only add that specific item:

```
addToCart(id){
    if(Meteor.userId()){
        this.state.productsList.forEach(product => {
            if(id == product._id)
                Carts.insert({
                    _id:product._id,
                    itemName: product.itemName,
                    itemDesc:product.itemDesc,
                    uploadedAt:new Date().getTime(),
                    price:product.price,
                    addedBy:Meteor.userId()
                });
        });
    }else{
        console.log('Please login to add this product');
    }
}
```